# DNS Server being Accessed by Internal and External Host

Tags: dns

I came across of a situation in which I can see internal ip and external ip accessing a corporate dns server. I do not know if the dns server is internal dns or external dns. I have very limited information.

What will be the use case for this kind of set up? What are the potential security risk?

Comment: What avoids to check the local network params and the current dns address? It would be visible on the first spot, where is the dns. Btw, I think it is a little bit too broad and maybe opinion-based. I don't think it would have a direct security relation.

Comment: Little information was provided to me. What I do know that is DNS server is connected to both the intranet and internet. I am hoping to understand what is the rational of have this setup so that I can better improve the security with minimal disruptions

Comment: Ok, but you can see its ip and network oarams, isn't? It is not a security issue, it is more like a serverfault or gesystem stability issue, in my opinion. A dns with 2 ips are essentially 2 different dns in the view of the client systems. It doesn't has to do any specific with security.

Comment: So a design like this that exposes a DNS server to internet and intranet are actually meant for having two dns zones? One for resolving host in intranet and one for resolving host for internet?

Comment: In this case is is safe to do something like this? What I usually see is that there are usually 2 dns servers one in the DMZ for external use and behind the firewall serving the intranet only.

Comment: In the security, only the "it is unsafe" answers are categoric. You can't say from a system that it is safe, you can only say if it is unsafe. But I don't see a systematic security flaw here which  would result directly from this configuration.